# Can't get data attribute from a selected option in a dynamically built table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, enums

I'm building a table and populating it with a column that has an enum drop down list. I want to get the attribute `data-yogaspaceid` of the select element when it has been changed. I can trigger the change event but the attribute 'data-yogaspaceid' that I'm trying to retrieve keeps returning as 'undefined'

Here is the select tag and javascript

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#statusDropDown', function() {
    // yogaSpaceid keeps coming up undefined
    var yogaSpaceId = $("#statusDropDown").find(':selected').attr('data-yogaspaceid');
  });
});
```

```html
<td>
    <select class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Status field is required." data-yogaspaceid="12" id="statusDropDown" name="item.Status"><option value="0">Listed</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Unlisted</option>
    </select>                        
</td>
```

The variable `yogaSpaceId` should have the value `12` but instead it is `undefined`

Comment: The data attribute is on the `select`, not on the `option`s

Comment: You just want `$(this).attr('data-yogaspaceid')`

Answer (score 1):

You have the data on the `<select>`, but you're trying to read it from the selected `<option>`. Just read it from the `<select>` itself:

```
var yogaSpaceId = $(this).attr('data-yogaspaceid');
```